# Alfresco form filters

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm trying to create a form filter, that would do some post-processing of a form.

What I'm trying to achieve:
Everytime a node has been created OR modified the filter should be applied after the node is persisted.

It runs just fine when i edit/modify an existing, but it does not run after a new node is created.

Here is my code:

```
    public class CaseFormFilter extends AbstractFilter<Object, NodeRef>
{
    protected ServiceRegistry registry; 
    protected NodeService nodeService;
    protected SearchService searchService;
    protected SiteService siteService;
    protected NamespaceService namespaceService;

    public void setServiceRegistry (ServiceRegistry registry) 
    { 
        this.registry      = registry;
        this.nodeService   = this.registry.getNodeService();
        this.searchService = this.registry.getSearchService();
        this.siteService   = this.registry.getSiteService();
        this.namespaceService = this.registry.getNamespaceService();

    }

    @Override public void afterPersist(Object item, FormData data, NodeRef persistedObject)
    {
    System.out.println("Persisting!");

    }

    @Override public void afterGenerate(Object item, List fields, List forcedFields, Form form, Map context) 
    {
        System.out.println("Calling afterGenerate!!");
    }

    @Override public void beforeGenerate(Object item, List fields,
                      List forcedFields, Form form, Map context) 
    {
        System.out.println("Calling beforeGenerate!!");
    }

    @Override public void beforePersist(Object item, FormData data) 
    {
        System.out.println("Calling beforePersist!!");

    }

}
```

I can see that `beforeGenerate` and `afterGenerate` is always called, even when viewing, which makes sense. 
However, `afterPersist` is only run when I edit a node, but not when creating a new node.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something? The wiki/documentation is rather useless on this point, reading http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms_Developer_Guide#Form_Filter just tells me to look in the DOD5015 module, which does provide an example, but does not really provide any answers.

I'm using Alfresco 4.0.b Community edition.

EDIT: A bit more clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to register your form filter **twice**. I'm guessing you currently only register it with the `nodeFilterRegistry`. For a form based on the content model (creating a node) you need to register your filter with the `typeFilterRegistry`.

Here is an example for a form filter configuration with both registries:

```
<bean id="yourFormFilterNode" class="com.domain.YourFormFilter" parent="baseFormFilter">
    <property name="filterRegistry" ref="nodeFilterRegistry" />
    <property name="nodeService" ref="nodeService" />
</bean>

<bean id="yourFormFilterType" class="com.domain.YourFormFilter" parent="baseFormFilter">
    <property name="filterRegistry" ref="typeFilterRegistry" />
    <property name="nodeService" ref="nodeService" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! It works after registering with the typeFilter. Now I just have to figure out what it actually sends over as the persisted object, but at least my method is run now!

Comment: I wonder how you could know stuff like this, the documentation/wiki is very unclear about it :/

Comment: You are right the documentation on that is lacking. I had to piece it together from blog posts and source code when I used it the first time.

Comment: Ahh I see. I actually went and updated the wiki to make this more clear, hopefully it can save other people some time ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's rather obvious that afterPersist is only called when submitted, because on viewing you're not 'persisting' any data.

So in most case you'll only need before/afterGenerate.

Comment: I don't want it to run when viewing, I want it to run after i create a new node from a form. It works fine when I edit existing nodes, but not when creating.

Comment: You want to run it after creating a new node. But what do you want to do? Do you want to change some node specific date? Then you could use a Behaviour (Policy). So first clarify what you really want to gain.

Comment: I'm setting a lot of different custom properties after the node is saved, something similar to the records management/dod5015 module, a unique ID and other stuff.
My custom code worked just fine, it just didn't run on create new nodes, because I needed to register it twice with nodeFilterRegistry and typeFilterRegistry.